# Javascript, php, HTML and CSS what next

Tags: php, javascript, html

I just now completed javascript in 24 hours now i want to move to advanced javascript, can someone suggest me advanced javascript books. I am pretty well versed in HTML and CSS and a novice at PHP. Me and my friend are planning to create a website(think it as a social networking site for college or something similar to that) so what should i learn to do that. Is PHP JS and HTML are enough? Can you suggest me books for this. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions here are often about actual programming problems, and often involve some code - so you're question is likely to be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) as off-topic. Don't take it personally; just check out the faq for [an explanation of what kind of questions you can ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: NodeJS, Mongo, Rails, Python, everything you can really. Why stop there?

Comment: I think this link answers your question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

Comment: Just answer all questions that run along under the tag [tag:javascript] and if you're fluent with that I'd say you know javascript. You don't need a book at all first-hand to get advanced, but practice.

Answer (score 2):

24 hours isn't enough to fully understand any language beyond its syntax and how to accomplish some basic tasks. Before tackling a large social networking project, try to make smaller, simpler programs or layouts.

To fully realize your social network, you'll need to know PHP (or Ruby, or Python, or C++ if you're crazy), HTML, probably JS, and some sort of data store; usually an SQL implementation or one of the newer NoSQL databases. It's not something you can throw together in a week or a month unless you really know what you're doing.

Start small, with a blog or a forum engine. That alone will take weeks. Then work your way up.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest You to learn some security in php like `sql_injection` and `xss`.If you are familiar with them then you should learn some `ajax` with `javascript` and `jquery`.It will very helpful to provide a interactivity like `facebook`

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting the advice from Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5565018#5565018)

> if you want to become an expert programmer, google SOLID, buy GOF, buy POEAA, buy Clean Code, lookup GRASP, DDD, CQRS, DCI … but dont ask for PHP books. That's the most reasonable suggestion I can give you when you ask for Expert PHP books really.
>
> maybe start here: [ustream.tv/recorded/22783515](http://ustream.tv/recorded/22783515)

and you have just got he overview of language ... no one can be perfect in 24 hour even i think [john skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) cant do that so you need to learn at lease 2 month to get a good or ok level knowledge

and also there is a level of website like if you think you want to make a website for a college which might have not many feature you can do this by some knowledge of php ,html,jS,ajax and basic database but if you want to make eCommerce website or a website like so working than you need highest level of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of website you're trying to develop.

If you are looking for a highly interactive modern website, I would really suggest learning Flash, ActionScript, and continuing on JavaScript. Taking a good look into HTML standards and animation would also be extremely useful.

If you are looking for how to make an e-commerce website or something similar, improve your knowledge on PHP. Ajax in JavaScript is also extremely useful, as you don't want your customers waiting forever if you have a slow connection. SQL, along with some kind of database engine (I'd suggest MySQL) is mandatory, or your users can't buy anything. But that's far down the track.

I think most websites split into those two categories.

But then again, some beforehand practice is definitely needed. No book on sale, as far as I'm concerned, will give you enough knowledge to build your own good website straight up. It takes experience, and not just of coding, but more of the study of user friendliness and what makes up that.

Really depends on what you need. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Learn Web Security. Start with the book [Essential PHP Security](http://phpsecurity.org/). Then check out the question [What should every programmer know about web development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development) on programmers.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first read this post in Stack Exchange Programmers:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

It is a very similar question to yours, and has many helpful answers.